# Minimal Qt5 install to compile code

Tags: compiling, application-development, qt, qt5

I wrote a little program in C++ using Qt. Back when it was Qt4, in order for my friends to compile my program on their Ubuntu system, I would tell them, after getting my source files, to just run:

```
sudo apt install libqt4-dev
<navigate to sources directory>
qmake
make
```

Now that it is Qt5, I read somewhere that the new `libqt4-dev` is `qtdeclarative5-dev` so I told them to just type the code above with `qtdeclarative5-dev` instead of `libqt4-dev`. 
However `qmake` didn't work, it did: `qmake: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake': No such file or directory`. I quickly found a fix by appending `-qt5`:

```
sudo apt install qtdeclarative5-dev
<navigate to sources directory>
qmake -qt5
make
```

Is this the correct way to do this? Is there a lighter or quicker Qt install?

Answer (score 2):

Correct way to compile using only `qmake` command. 
You can install qt5-default package to set qt5 as default while using development binaries.

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-default qtdeclarative5-dev
```

Comment: "Your program was written in qt4 so it was searching qt4 binaries in system": Actually no, I have obtained the same error with another program written in Qt5. I don't know why it tried to compile with qt4.